# How can I complete the build of this Lunar lander from the Space and Airport Set (9335)?

Tags: building, instructions

We recently got [Space and Airport Set by LEGO® Education (9335)](https://education.lego.com/en-us/products/space-and-airport-set-by-lego-education/9335) for our four-year-old who loves space and really loves his Duplo. He's been enjoying putting together the different parts of the kit but we've run into a problem - for some reason, LEGO doesn't have instructions for a bunch of the elements in the set.

Inside the box, all of the pieces were bagged in unnumbered plastic bags but not by set, so we couldn't even guess which pieces were designed to go together. There's a card with all of the pieces included in the box, too, but not by set. There are instructions for four of the figures, one on each of four plastic cards, and there are a set of [instructions on the website](https://education.lego.com/en-us/support/earlylearning/building-instructions#space) for another five of the more complicated ones. That's nine out of what I'm guessing is 16 different builds, meaning 7 are missing instructions.

Some of the items are easy to figure out because you can see or guess all of the pieces just by looking at the images - for example, the rocket. But we're a bit stuck on the Lunar Lander because there are no images of the reverse side. If all of the pieces had been grouped in one bag, we could have figured it out pretty easily, I think but, as is, we're stuck.

Here's the image of it that's included in the set (which I've taken from the LEGO site link above):

[image: Official LEGO image of the space elements in this set, including a Mars rover, Lunar rover, Lunar lander, and a Lunar surface with two astronauts taking samples]
<sup>(Click to expand)</sup>

We started from the ground up and we've gotten this far:

[image: Photo of the base of the Lunar lander without the habitat section]
<sup>(Click to expand)</sup>

I'm not certain that the dark grey pieces are correct but they seem correct enough, so I'm not too worried. But now we need help figuring out the upper half. We have the white 6x6 for the base but there seems to be something between the light grey angle pieces that we have and the white 6x6, but I'm not sure what it is.

My husband and I have both dug around some on the internet but other full-set lunar landers are all that we see in search. Does anyone have an instruction set or can make an educated guess for which pieces we should use to build the rest of this lander?

---

While I'm focusing on this specific set, there are other parts like the airport itself that also don't have any instructions I can find. LEGO usually seems so good about showing you how to build things - and particularly for an educational product that's supposed to be used in a classroom by several children - it seems odd that they don't have instructions for this.

### Links:

- [Brickset](https://brickset.com/sets/9335-1/Space-Airport-Set)
- Brickfactory (can't link to the set)
- [Swooshable](https://swooshable.com/sets/9335-1) (images link to Brickfactory)

So, Brickfactory and Swooshable have the same six images - the front side of all five plastic cards in the box and the reverse of one of them.

Comment: If it helps, I'm happy to provide closer-up photos of the image provided in the box - it's the same image above but I may be able to get more detail than what you can see in the image above.

Comment: FYI: Parts in lego sets are grouped in bags which have numbers on them. In the instructions, they tell you to open these bags one at a time when they tell you to, but since this is older set i guess i can understand. Did you browse the set number on Brickset and look for instruction archives there?

Comment: I appreciate the comment and I'm aware of that - I can make it more clear but the bags in this set were not labeled and the instructions are not all-inclusive. I've watched a silly amount of LEGO builds on YouTube with my son and I'm well-aware of how these sets *usually* work - but this was not the case with this set. Instead of a paper sheet with all of the instructions or a booklet, there are six plastic cards with images of groups of the builds and instructions for a single build on the back of the card.

Comment: I updated my commemt, please read that last sentence. Im on mobile and I accidentally clicked the enter button when I wasn't finshed typing.

Comment: Brickset has links to Swooshable and Brickfactory - the former just links to the latter and Brickfactory just has scans of the plastic sheets I have - in fact, it doesn't even have scans of both sides of the sheets. :( So, unless I'm using the site wrong, it doesn't seem to have what I need.

Comment: Oh, you're right, those links seem to be broken and/or useless. At this point I'm stumped too, I don't know how to help you any farther.

Comment: Given it is an educational set that might follow different rules, I could imagine that the intent of not giving instructions is to make the students figure out themselves how to build the different items or giving the pictures more as an "inspiration". It reminds me a bit of the images on the boxes back in the 90s that showed alternative builds of a set but only in a single photo. Not that this insight would be of any help for your problem, though. ;-)

Answer (score 9):

The best I could find in terms of instructions for 9335 is [this page](https://www.teaching.com.au/product/LEG9335), which seem to contain all the prints included in the set. However Lunar lander is missing. It looks like one of those "inspiration" sets LEGO used to include in the old days. Looking at the pictures I found they are reasonable quality and model doesn't contain too many parts. So I gave a try building it digitally:

[image]

[image]

There are a few places like top white slopes, back [Light Bluish Gray](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp) [brick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2877#T=C) on top as well as 4x4 plate below first 6x6 white plate, where you couldn't tell the exact elements used. Apart from that everything seems to be pretty clear for me.

I could have shared the LDraw file as well, however not what would be the best way to do it here on SE.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful! I... uh... am a bit of a novice so I'm not sure what an "LBG brick" is - I did a Google search and it said "light blue grey"? Is that a 4x4 of the lighter grey like [this](https://www.lego.com/cdn/cs/set/assets/blt7a049fe2a311c2b1/4243797.jpg?fit=bounds&format=jpg&quality=80&width=100&height=100&dpr=1)?

Comment: @Catija I've added clarification about LBG, but you were very close. The brick I had in mind is [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2877#T=C)

Answer (score 5):

Alex has rendered a great model.

I can only offer my own take by adding the LEM ascent engine.

[image]

These are the parts I used:

[image]

You can find the LDraw file in my git repository [here](https://github.com/dsoze1138/LEM_9335).

Comment: 9335 set is from 2010, so it no longer contains any parts in Dark Gray or Light Gray colors.

Comment: @Alex,  It's unfortunate that the available colours in the set have been reduced. I did this as a CAD build working from the Bricklink inventory and what images Peeron would provide. I found all the parts in 9335 inventory but there could be some variations.